# Prolog: How to produce a multiple answer output?

Tags: prolog, clause

Given:

```
fruitid('Apple', 'Granny Smith', 1).
```

How would I go about creating the clause:

```
print_fruit_details(FruitID) :-
```

Which would output 'Apple' and 'Granny Smith' given the input 1.

Thanks,

JAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print_fruit_details(FruitID) :- fruitid(X, Y, FruitID), write(X), write(Y).
```

And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Ah so simple, yet once so troubling.

Thanks! I'm sure I'll be around here a lot.